# Changing CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, android-studio, environment-variables, capacitor

I'm trying to set up my development environment for CapacitorJS on Arch Linux.
I followed the documentation and added

`CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH=/usr/bin/android-studio`

to my systems environment variables (not the project) but I'm still getting the same error

```
[error] Unable to launch Android Studio. Is it installed?
        Attempted to open Android Studio at:
        /usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
        You can configure this with the CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH
        environment variable.
```

Even though It's ***never*** pointed to `/usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`

I ran `whereis android-studio` and got `android-studio: /usr/bin/android-studio`, so I thought that would be the correct path, but every time I run `npx cap open android` it says it's trying it launch from the same path and never changes

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you've installed it, for example Toolbox installs it inside the user's home directory.

`nano ~/.bashrc`

```
export CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH=~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/202.7486908/bin/studio.sh
```

`locate studio.sh` might be able to find it, too.

Comment: `whereis studio.sh` gave me `/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` so i changed my export to that, but its still trying to open from the original path.

Comment: could you solve it, the same thing is happening to me?

Comment: After you've changed the export in your ~/.bashrc, you should restart your terminal/bash, so it will actually load the variables.

Comment: I fixed this by running `whereis android-studio` and then saving that path into `.bashrc`